# Application of Hilbert's basis theorem in representation theory

Tags: algebraic-geometry, representation-theory

In [Smalø: Degenerations of Representations of Associative Algebras, Milan J. Math., 2008](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00032-007-0082-8) there is an application of Hilbert's basis theorem that I don't understand:

Two orders are defined on the set of $d$-dimensional modules over an algebra $\Lambda$ that is finite dimensional over a field. One by $M\leq_{\operatorname{Hom}} N$ iff $\dim \operatorname{Hom}(X,M)\leq \dim \operatorname{Hom}(X,N)$ for all $X$ and one by $M\leq_n N$ iff $\dim \operatorname{Hom}(\Lambda^n/\Lambda^nA,M)\leq \dim \operatorname{Hom}(\Lambda^n/\Lambda^nA,N)$ for all $n\times n$-matrices $A$. It is now claimed that from Hilbert's basis theorem for $n$ large enough (depending on $d$) one gets that $\leq_n$ is equivalent to $\leq_{\operatorname{Hom}}$. Can somebody provide a more detailed argument?

**ADDED by David E Speyer** The problem here is that the set $\{ (M,N) : M \leq_n N \}$ is neither Zariski closed nor Zariski open. (Take $\Lambda = k[\epsilon]/\epsilon^2$ and $d=2$. So $\mathrm{rep}_2 \Lambda$ (in the notation of the paper) is the space of $2 \times 2$ matrices with square zero. Then two matrices $\rho$ and $\sigma$ in $\mathrm{rep}_2 \Lambda$ obey $\rho \leq_1 \sigma$ if and and only if either $\sigma =0$ or $\rho \neq 0$.) If these spaces were Zariski closed, this would be an easy consequence of Hilbert's basis theorem but, as it is, I am stumped.

Comment: Edits remove two ambiguities in the original question (what finite dimensional means, and what $n$ is allowed to depend on), based on my reading of the article. Then added a paragraph to point out what doesn't work here.

Comment: @DavidSpeyer. It is a general rule on SE sites that posts should not contain visible edit history. They should read smoothly.

Comment: The question was recently edited to roll back most of an edit from over five years ago, on the grounds that it was "quite harmful". I don't want to get into an edit war, but I don't see what was harmful about that old edit. In fact, I think it was a helpful addition of context to indicate how Hilbert's basis theorem might be relevant to a question like this, and to explain why one simple approach to applying it doesn't work in this case.

Comment: A few questions: what does it mean for $M,N$ to be $d$-dimensional over $\Lambda$? Second, what is $X$ (a finitely generated $\Lambda$ module?) in the definition of $\leq_{Hom}$?

Comment: @Mindlack $\Lambda$ is an algebra over a field. It means $d$-dimensional over that field. And yes, $X$ is a finitely generated $\Lambda$-module (the original paper of Smalø says this explicitly).

Comment: I restored the edit. It was there for years, without a very strong and clear-cut reason it won't be removed now.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I found the following, in the introduction of the [2015 PhD thesis](https://ntnuopen.ntnu.no/ntnu-xmlui/bitstream/handle/11250/2364946/Nils_Nornes_PhD.pdf?sequence=1) of Nils Nornes, a student of Smalø:

> In [[7]](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021869310000244), cowritten with my fellow student Tore A. Forbregd and our
> adviser Professor Sverre O. Smalø, we show that $\leq_{d^3}$ always is a partial
> order on $\operatorname{mod}_d\Lambda$. It seems like for large enough $n$, $\leq_n$ is equivalent to
> $\leq_{\operatorname{Hom}}$. In the paper we claimed this as a fact, but we did not give a
> proof. When the reviewer requested a proof, we realized that the proof
> we had in mind was incomplete. We decided to remove the statement,
> but unfortunately we wrote it twice and deleted it once, so it still
> appears in the published version.
> While we have not found a proof, we have not found any counterexample either. In fact, in all examples we have looked at, $\leq_n$ is either not
> a partial order or equivalent to $\leq_{\operatorname{Hom}}$. We still have no examples where
> $\leq_n$ is a partial order but is different from $\leq_{\operatorname{Hom}}$.